# Check and Uncheck CheckBox using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a GridView on a click of a header checkbox. I want to check all CheckBox in ItemTemplate.

I have tried implementing through Jquery but it didn't work, as

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=ChkSelectAll.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            $('#<%=ChkSelectAll.ClientID %>').is(":checked")(function () {
                $('#<%=ChkSelect.ClientID %>').prop('checked', true);
            });
        });
    });
```

I have a Gridview as

```
<Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="20px">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkSelectAll" runat="server"  />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkSelect" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
</Column>
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: can you make fiddle for your html output ????????

Comment: Sir it shows an error, that ChkSelectAll control could not be found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdjrX/) out.if you have many checkbox than use class instead of id because ID should be unique

```
$('#ChkSelectAll').click(function () {
if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $('.ChkSelect').prop('checked', true);
}
});
```

EDITED CODE with [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cY6La/)

```
$('#ChkSelectAll').click(function () {
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $('.ChkSelect').prop('checked', true);
  }else{
    $('.ChkSelect').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

Comment: Sir,if we want to uncheck the checkbox then we will use if($(this).is(":Unchecked"))???

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#ChkSelectAll").click(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")){
$('#ChkSelect').attr('checked', true);
}
else{
$('#ChkSelect').attr('checked', false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The gridview will have unique id of for each row so you can not changing all of them using single id.

Change

```
$('#<%=ChkSelect.ClientID %>').prop('checked', true);
```

To

```
$('[id*=ChkSelect]').prop('checked', true);
```

You can shorten your code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#<%=ChkSelectAll.ClientID %>').click(function () {           
            $('[id*=ChkSelect]').prop('checked', this.checked);           
      });
});
```

Comment: Sir, what is the difference between '#<%=ChkSelect.ClientID %>' and '[id*=ChkSelect]' ??

Comment: The expression '#<%=ChkSelect.ClientID %>' will give you exactly one element matching the id whereas  '[id*=ChkSelect]' will give you all elements which contain ChkSelect in their id, it uses wild card *

Answer (score 0):

I tried several solutions found here on stackoverflow and none of them worked. I used jquery-1.9.1.min.js and chrome to test it. Here is my working solution

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#goOffline').click(function(event) {
    if($('#goOffline').is(':checked')){
        $('#goOffline').attr("checked","checked");
    } else {
        $('#goOffline').removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```

});

What is basically happen is that I select the checkbox element by using $('#goOffline') atach on click event. Then I test if it is checked or not. If it is checked than attach attribute checked, if not, then remove attribute checked. Note that my html input markup looks like following:

```
<label for="goOffline" class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="goOffline" id="goOffline">
    Go offline
</label>
```